# Mongdb look let uses the fields in the previous lookup result

Tags: mongodb, lookup

**i want use $c.cid**

How does this js work?

this customer_url as c  and lookup customer use customer_url.cid

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "customer_url",
        localField: "url_id",
        foreignField: "url_id",
        as: "c"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$c"
},
{
    $lookup: {
        as: "customer",
        from: "customer_dim",
        let: {
            cid: "$c.cid"
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $eq: ["$_id", "$$cid"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: this cid:"$c.cid" not work

Comment: your sytax is correct. make sure lookup matches are actually formed.